# recursive sqlite query given a parent id

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have  a sqlite  database with this structure

```
create table categories
                ( CategoryID       integer     not null  primary key
                , CategoryName     text not null
                , CategoryParentID integer     null
                ,FOREIGN KEY (CategoryParentID) REFERENCES categories(CategoryID)
                );
```

And given a parent ID i want to have all the descendants (as a tree) with n levels, but i don't know how to do it. 
Really appreciate your help on this.

I already have something like this, but i dont know where to put the parent id condition to start the search

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_categories (categorias.CategoryID, categorias.CategoryName, categorias.CategoryParentID, depth) AS (
SELECT categorias.CategoryID, categorias.CategoryName, categorias.CategoryParentID, 1
FROM categorias
WHERE categorias.CategoryParentID IS NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT c.CategoryID, c.CategoryName, c.CategoryParentID, r.depth + 1
FROM categories AS c
INNER JOIN cte_categories AS r ON (c.CategoryParentID = r.CategoryID)
)
SELECT CategoryName, depth, CategoryParentID
FROM cte_categories ORDER BY depth, CategoryName;
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html). Or some [other documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).